# Can't send mails to 'openid-specs-ab@lists.openid.net'

Tags: openid, openid-connect

I need to send mails to 'openid-specs-ab@lists.openid.net' to get some details about OpenIDConnect Session Management. I subscribed to the list. I'm receiving the mails from them too. But I can't post mails. It is highly appreciated if anybody can help me to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to sign a contributor agreement first. Once you have done this, you will be able to post to the list. You can find the [OIDC Contributor Agreement](https://openid.net/intellectual-property/) on the OpenID Foundation's web site. If you run into trouble, you can [contact the foundation](https://openid.net/foundation/contact/) for support.